# Java script radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Javascript and radio buttons for the first time.

I need to know how to assign the script to each radio button that is selected? there seem to be a few ways of doing this and its just getting confusing!

Each question has 4 radio buttons to select from and I need to gather the answers at the end!

Any help appreciated

Comment: What did you code so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just add an event listener to the radio buttons and maintain a mapping where you could store all your answers to.

```js
let answers = {}

$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function (event) {
  let question = event.currentTarget.name
  let answer = event.currentTarget.value
  answers[question] = answer
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(answers, null, 2)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-block">
  <div class="question">
    1. Which one is the biggest?
  </div>
  <div class="answers">
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="1" checked> Elephant<br>
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="2"> Whale<br>
      <input type="radio" name="1" value="3"> Giraffe
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="question-block">
  <div class="question">
    2. Which one is the smallest animal?
  </div>
  <div class="answers">
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="2" value="1" checked> Bacteria<br>
      <input type="radio" name="2" value="2"> Virus<br>
      <input type="radio" name="2" value="3"> Ant
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```